# Same answer from different users on different questions

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates

There are almost duplicate questions, and not very surprisingly they have similar answers. But one answer is an exact copy, though posted from a different account. The newer version is slightly more extensive.

- [Older answer from 31. 8. 2012](https://superuser.com/a/468498/194976)
- [Newer answer from 6. 12. 2014](https://superuser.com/a/849347/194976)

I'm not aware of any policy on duplicate answers as long as they are correct, but what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I would consider that plagiarism.  An entire 4-paragraph answer was lifted word-for-word without attribution.  I agree with nKn.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, excerpts of already posted answers are ok *as long as they respect original authorship*, e.g. including a link to the original answer.

If the newer answers are blatant copies (which in my opinion also involves the case you mention) of existing answers, I'd flag for moderator attention explaining this is a copy of an already posted answer so they may take any needed actions.

Comment: They should also use appropriate quote markup (`>`). See [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing)

Comment: In such a case that an answer can be directly copied would indicate the question should be closed as a duplicate. Reminds me of [the time](https://superuser.com/questions/986313/why-cant-you-run-os-x-on-a-pc/986315#986315) I quoted a quote of @JourneymanGeek